# Display entries that belong to a category

Tags: templating, categories

I have a page that should show entries within a category, and then entries within children of that category. Basically, I need a way to loop through entries that have a level 1 category but not a level 2 category.

To give an example, suppose I've got some categories set up like this:

1.

— 1.1.

—— 1.1.1.

— 1.2.

2.

There's also one entry related to each category. I'd then use code like this:

```
{# Reference the category #}
{% set cat = craft.categories.title('1.').first() %}

{# Find related entries #}
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('mySection').relatedTo(cat).find() %}

{# Print them out #}
{% for entry in entries %}
    <p>{{ entry.title }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

This would output:

1.

1.1.

1.1.1.

1.2.

How can I find entries which are **directly** related to the category “1.”?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Categories are Craft's implementation of a taxonomy, which itself is the classification of things into groups and sub-groups. In this respect, I suppose it makes sense that if an entry is related to a sub-category, it inherits (it's also related to) its parent. That would explain why you're getting all entries in this way.

At the moment, the only way I can think of is to test what level the category/sub-category is.

Something like this would get you started for the time being. I don't really like this because it seems convoluted, so I'll put my thinking cap on and I may revise.

```
{% set category = craft.categories.group('myGroup').title('1.').first() %}
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('mySection').relatedTo(category).find() %}
{% set isThisLevel = false %}
{% for entry in entries %}

    {# Test if this entry is related to the correct category level #}
    {% for relatedCat in entry.catField %}
        {% if relatedCat.level == category.level %}
            {% set isThisLevel = true %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}

    {# Only output if it's this category level #}
    {% if isThisLevel %}
        {# Do whatever you want #}
    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This is how I thought it would work, however there is seemingly no way to assign a level 2 category to an entry without it inheriting the level 1 category.

Therefore, I can't loop through entries with a level 1 category, but not a level 2 category; the entries with a level 2 category inherently have a level 1 category and there seems to be no way to exclude them.

Comment: Ah right, I didn't totally understand the situation. I've revised my answer but I'm still not happy with it. I'll have a think. I've also submitted a modification to the question to clarify the problem.

Comment: Yeah, sorry my question was so vague I didn't know how to word it. I actually came to the same solution as the one you've suggested. Works fine but it's a little gross.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`level`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/craft.categories#level) parameter of a Categories ElementCriteriaModel to get a list of nth-level categories, just to make your category search a bit more robust.

Then, you can use Twig's `without` filter to create the set of entries related to the primary category but *not* related to its child categories:

```
{# Identify the primary category you want #}
{% set cat = craft.categories.title('1.').level(1).first() %}

{# Identify the [child] categories you don't want #}
{# set childCats = cat.children #}

{# Grab an array of entries related to the primary category #}
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('mySection').relatedTo(cat).find() %}

{# Get an array of entries related to the child categories #}
{% set excludedEntries = craft.entries.section('mySection').relatedTo(childCats).find() %}

{# Exclude the second set and loop over the resulting array #}
{% for entry in entries|without(excludedEntries) %}
    <p>{{ entry.title }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

This is still a bit janky, and you'd have to tweak it for performance if you were interested in more than one primary category at a time... but maybe it's a start.